# Trailing Slash issues with Search Engines

Tags: .htaccess, slash, canonical-link

When websites return page content with or without a trailing slash on their URLs, Search Engines might see these as separate pages with duplicate content which they could penalize. So how to use a 301 redirect to force search engines to see the correct version of a website ?

I tried with a .htaccess but was not successful.
I am not interested to add canonical meta tag in every page.

ISSUE;

> example.com/siteinfo/user/login
>
> example.com/siteinfo/user/login/

should not show  same content.

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your .htaccess to redirect without slash:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Or for the version with slash:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: This is not working - I even tried as below - Not Successful   RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]